# Is there an official glossary of intellectual property terms in the UK?

Tags: united-kingdom, intellectual-property, legal-terms

I am writing a research paper on how intellectual property rights terminology in Russia compares to that in the UK. I am looking for an official glossary or a standard approved by the UK government that includes all major terms used in the UK legislation. Is there such a thing? I have not found anything like that on legislation.gov.uk

Answer (score 1):

This pdf [Glossary of Terms: Intellectual Property and Related Areas of Law](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://www.everymanadvisory.co.uk/wpcms/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/Fact-Sheet-Glossary-of-Terms-Intellectual-Property-and-Related-Areas-of-Law.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwjJm73ysezvAhUqQkEAHV6PBcAQFjAAegQIBBAC&usg=AOvVaw3wDhWkZGN7JVPGwnP2wH7c&cshid=1617810309331) seems pretty comprehensive, and [Gov.UK](https://www.gov.uk/intellectual-property-an-overview/protect-your-intellectual-property) has various links that may assist.